# Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000

Tags: node.js, nodemon

Every time I save some changes to the server, nodemon fails to refresh the server with the following error:

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000
```

I've been using `sudo lsof -i :5000` and then `kill -9 [PID]` to resolve it but I've to do it every 2 mins or so.
Any permanent solution so that the server is actually killed and then restarted on refresh?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nodemon: Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::5000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61181302/nodemon-error-listen-eaddrinuse-address-already-in-use-5000)

Comment: No it does not. When i use `node index` , it works a few times but then start giving out the error again. I make sure no other instances are running. It's just ctrl+c doesn't kill the server sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as yours.

In my situation, my IDE is VSCode and I use the **integrated terminal**. The problem is even we close server with Ctrl+C (or Ctrl+Z), the server is actually not stop. So you should close the whole VSCode (or your other IDE) window and reopen it.

Comment: That's not a fix. Would just add to the trouble, apart from the agony restarting vs code would bring, I'd have to restart the client and server both now.

Comment: Would just kill the whole point of having something like 'nodemon'

Answer (score 0):

try this two command in Terminal-

```
sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=582222 && sudo sysctl -p

sudo sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=582222
```

I hope will help you.