# I got node:events:346

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemon

I made a new node project with npm init.

When I enter command
`➜ nodemon index.js`

I got Error

```
[nodemon] 2.0.15
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node index.js`
node:events:346
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3003
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1311:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1359:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1446:7)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/media/keval/New Volume1/‍️ KEVAL ACTIVITY/️ Skills/️ Programming/Builds/JavaScript/React-Native/Zoom/zoom-clone-api/index.js:12:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1092:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1121:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:972:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47
Emitted 'error' event on Server instance at:
    at emitErrorNT (node:net:1338:8)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:81:21) {
  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -98,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 3003
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting..
```

and I am using LINUX(UBUNTU)
so how can I avoid this.

and thankyou in advance for helping me.

Comment: `listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::3003` means another process is listening on port 3003. Kill that process or use a different port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. One way of doing it is to running `pkill -f nodemon` and then restart the server
2. You could also apply a delay to your `nodemon` instance as such :

   nodemon --delay 500ms index.js

This link sums up the rest for you :

[nodemon Error resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66239788/16067048)

You should also add :

```js
process.once('SIGUSR2', function () {
  process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGUSR2');
});

process.on('SIGINT', function () {
  // this is only called on ctrl+c, not restart
  process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGINT');
});
```

Comment: I just updated my answer

Comment: the link shared had a answer for it which was tyle `pkill -f nodemon` then restart the server. thankyou

Comment: You're welcome, I am glad it worked !

Comment: you can also add this to your answer. and thankyou for sharing the link with me

Comment: I am using nodemon for first time on my linux . so, having some problems

Comment: what does this snippit do

Comment: I just edited my post

Comment: It helps you develop Node JS based apps by automatically restarting your app threw your CLI

Comment: You can find more information about nodemon with this link : https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon

Comment: Since I updated my answer as you asked, can you re-validate my answer ? Thanks @KevalShah